# How to combine two awk commands into a single line

Tags: bash, awk

how can I combine the following two awk commands into a single line:

```
awk -F= '$1=="ID" { print $2 ;}' /etc/*release && awk -F= '$1=="VERSION_ID" { print $2 ;}' /etc/*release | xargs
```

Im trying to get the linux distribution and os in a single line, in the format distribution+version.
For example: ubuntu20.04, rhel7.5

Comment: Will `*release` match 1 file or more than 1? The correct answer to your question depends on the answer to that question and if the answer is "more than 1" then none of the currently posted answers will produce the same output as your 2 commands (assuming both target strings exist in all `*release` files so if that's not the case tell us about that too). Please provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture each part into a variable and then print them out once you have processed the file:

```
awk -F= '$1=="ID"{id=$2}$1=="VERSION_ID"{vid=$2}END{print id,vid}' /etc/*release
```

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`:

```
source /etc/os-release; echo "$ID $VERSION_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want the quotes (as in your example), in that case:

```
awk -F '["=]' '$1=="ID" {printf("%s,",$3)} $1=="VERSION_ID" {printf("%s\n",$3)}' < /etc/*release
```

Comment: this may end up having a trailing `,` instead of `\n` if only `ID` existed in the input